# Not able to Build the Angular Project

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

As complete bootstrap functionality doesn't work in Angular 2+ project. So i implemented ngx-bootstrap in my project. but now i am getting error while "ng -build --prod"  command.

Below is the error i am getting.

Can anyone please help in resolving this.

```
chunk {0} styles.6c291e9c3580c6b47b03.bundle.css (styles) 179 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} polyfills.997d8cc03812de50ae67.bundle.js (polyfills) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main.ee32620ecd1edff94184.bundle.js (main) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js (inline) 796 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in src\app\layout\component\header\header.component.html(20,43): : Property 'isCollapsed' does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'.
src\app\layout\component\header\header.component.html(16,73): : Property 'isCollapsed' does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'.
src\app\layout\component\header\header.component.html(16,73): : Property 'isCollapsed' does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'.
```

<--HTML file goes here-->

Hello

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [collapse]="!isCollapsed">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li dropdown class="nav-item active dropdown border-left border-right " style="font-size:16px!important">
          <a dropdownToggle  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="cursor:pointer">link1</a>
          <div *dropdownMenu  class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/link2">link2</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/link3">link3 Details</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/link4">link4</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item  active border-right  " style="font-size:16px!important">
            <a class="nav-link " routerLink="/link5">link5</a>
          </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As the error is at header.component.html(16,73), please post your html and possibly the typescript also.

Comment: Hi Jun, I am using ngx-bootstrap, so i am using inbuilt ngx-bootstrap functionalities. which is running when i do ng serve, but getting error on ng build.

Comment: That doesn't matter and has nothing to do with this error. You can't property bind to a property that hasn't been declared in your Typescript.

Answer (score 4):

You must declare property `isCollapsed` in your TypeScript class `HeaderComponent` if you want to use it in your HTML view.

Ex:

```
public isCollapsed: boolean;
```

Otherwise, you can remove all calls of your property `isCollapsed` in your template "header.component.html".

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({ 
selector: 'toggle-manual-demo', 
templateUrl: './toggle-manual.html' 
}) 

export class ToggleManualDemoComponent { 
    isCollapsed = false; 
}
```

Comment: do i have to stop using the ngx-bootstrap functionalities? and use manual function instead? because currently i am using ngx-bootstrap predefined. which is on ngx bootstrap site

Comment: No, the built in functionalities work however, you still need to declare the property you are binding to in your typescript. Without the property, the html does not know if [collapse] is true or false as Angular believes isCollapsed is undefined

Comment: Read the doc here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/collapse You can see there is a declared property in the "component" tab

Comment: Thanks All for the help , worked like a charm. i did silly mistake over there.